# Fill clipped area with color

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, hlsl, clipping

I'd like to achieve an effect in XNA where I move a clipping plane through an object, and the object gradually disappears WHILE the clipped area is filled with a custom color or texture.

This is what I was able to achieve via HLSL:

[image]

And this is what I would actually need:

[image]

I think the teapot isn't a really great example because the models I would use would always be fully closed at all times.

Are there any good solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that if  you just have calculated if a pixel is front or back, you don´t need to clip it if the pixel is front, you only should set the pixel normal to the plane normal value, and calculate light as usual...